# Компиляция многофайлового проекта в vscode на MacOS

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, link

Искал информацию в интернете, но толком ничего не нашел. Есть ли способ собрать такой проект без доп. плагинов и боли? Мне кажется, что нужно добавить\изменить аргумент в tasks.json

task.json:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: clang сборка активного файла",
            "command": "/usr/bin/clang++",
            "args": [
                "-std=c++20",
                "-stdlib=libc++",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "компилятор: /usr/bin/clang++"
        }
    ]
}
```

---

Ошибка:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Hello::getText()", referenced from:
      _main in test-15da43.o
  "Hello::Hello(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >)", referenced from:
      _main in test-15da43.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Используйте любую систему сборки cmake, make, ninja

Comment: Спасибо, я уже разобрался. Надо было просто добавить в tasks.json путь ко всем cpp файлам